# How to read through two files in bash to create a list of nested output to parallelise a command

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, parallel-processing, nested

I have been using bash to generate a list of analysis commands like so:

```
while read sample control; do echo analysis --target $sample --control $control --output /path/to/results/$sample/'$sample'_output.txt >> /path/to/commands/commands.txt ; done < sample_list.txt
```

The input file sample_list.txt looks like this

```
sample_A control_A
sample_B control_B
```

However I want to make something more complicated where for each of these commands I run it over a subset of the data to parallelise the analysis so it runs faster. I can do this by adding an option '--interval-list' and giving a subset of the total data to analyse. But I don't know who to loop over this together with the sample list in an efficient way.

The end command I imagine would be something like this:

```
while read sample control regions; do echo analysis --target $sample --control $control --interval-list $regions --output /path/to/results/$sample/'$sample'_'$regions'_output.txt >> /path/to/commands/commands.txt ; done < sample_list.txt
```

For example for the first 2 set of samples I'd want to now have 20 commands output instead of 2. With these variables:

```
sample_A control_A Region_1
sample_A control_A Region_2
sample_A control_A Region_3
sample_A control_A Region_4
sample_A control_A Region_5
sample_A control_A Region_6
sample_A control_A Region_7
sample_A control_A Region_8
sample_A control_A Region_9
sample_A control_A Region_10
sample_B control_B Region_1
sample_B control_B Region_2
sample_B control_B Region_3
sample_B control_B Region_4
sample_B control_B Region_5
sample_B control_B Region_6
sample_B control_B Region_7
sample_B control_B Region_8
sample_B control_B Region_9
sample_B control_B Region_10
```

and an example output line would be:

```
analysis --target sample_A --control control_A --interval-list Region_1 --output /path/to/results/sample_A/sample_A_Region_1_output.txt
```

I could just put the lines above into the sample_list.txt file but that kind of defeats the point of an efficient loop. I think I need a sample_list.txt file and a separate regions.txt file as the input for the --interval-list variable, so it can loop through the 10 regions for each line in sample_list.txt file if that makes sense. Sort of like a loop within a loop.

But I don't know how to fit the regions.txt file into this in a way that makes it easier than manually writing out all the combinations.

The input for the regions.txt file would be like this:

```
Region_1
Region_2
Region_3
Region_4
Region_5
Region_6
Region_7
Region_8
Region_9
Region_10
```

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the regions into an array and loop over the regions in an inner loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read regions into an array
mapfile -t regions < regions.txt

while read sample control; do
  for region in "${regions[@]}"; do # loop over regions
    echo "analysis --target $sample --control $control --output /path/to/results/$sample/${sample}_${region}_output.txt"
  done
done < sample_list.txt > /path/to/commands/commands.txt # write output to commands.txt
```